Change file content after esbuild transform
I would like to change the content of the file after esbuild has done its transform. E.g.,
my-file.ts
function myFunction() {
  console.log('My function was called.')
}

export default myFunction

Then esbuild transforms it to (npx esbuild --format=esm ./my-file.ts):
function myFunction() {
  console.log("My function was called.");
}
var my_file_default = myFunction;
export {
  my_file_default as default
};

I would like to write a plugin to change the content above to this:
function myFunction() {
  console.log("My function was called.");
}
return myFunction;

If I change the export to a return statement before esbuild does its transform esbuild throws an error since it is a module.
Why am I doing this? I would like to have a module system for a service worker. Since that hasn't been implemented yet I have created one myself. It works fine for my purposes but I would like to stream line the build process. I already have the code to change the content. But right now I'm waiting until the changes are done by esbuild and then reading the files that esbuild created and making the changes through a separate build step. I would rather that it all just happen in memory. But I didn't see a post content change hook in esbuild and was wondering if I was missing something.

Does the below sufficient?
function createPluginFunction() {
    return new Function(`return "Plugin result";`);
}

const plugin = createPluginFunction();


No, that is pretty much what it was outputting already. I need to get rid of the export as it won't work in a new Function call.

Check edit of new option, maybe
